# .net linked server query could not find 'SRVSQL01' in sysservers

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need to execute this query in a VB .net program on linked servers

```
SELECT * 
FROM [SRVSQL01].[TARIF].[dbo].[CPTGCHKSYNCVIEW] L
LEFT JOIN [SRVSQL03].[TARIF].[dbo].[CPTGCHKSYNCVIEW] R ON L.CG_Num = R.CG_Num
```

When I execute this query in SSMS, it's working.

But when I execute it from my VB.net program, I get the following error:

> Could not find 'SRVSQL01' in sysservers

I'm using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

I forgot to tell something very important, this program is working on one of my servers. The connection string is the same:

```
server=SRVSQL03;Trusted_Connection=True;Database=TARIF;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct DB ?

Comment: Sound like there is an error in the connection string.  The connection string should be the same instance of the Server you see in the SSMS login window.

Comment: Did you try this qry from managament studio? It seems there not exists linked server in SRVSQL03 to connect SRVSQL01. Try run select * from sys.sysservers on SRVSQL03.

Comment: Yes i tried on SSMS and it's working! And SRVSQL01 appear when i select * FROM sys.sysservers

Answer (score 0):

As @sagi said, i checked my program and discover that i was always connecting to the same server...
So i corrected the program and now it's working.